# PDFBox (2.1.0): When printed from IE11, transparent text watermark has opaque background

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT in a Java 8 Spring Boot app to add a transparent text watermark on each page of an otherwise image-only PDF document. Visually, it works fine, as I'm able to see the image through the watermark on any reader and all browser-inline PDF Viewers.

However, when I print these documents from IE, an opaque white background covers up the image behind the text. The watermark text is still transparent, but the bounding box of the text is white. Again, printing from all other browsers works fine. (Gotta love IE.)

Here's the code I'm using to add the watermark to each page:

```
public void watermark(File pdfFile, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try (final InputStream sourceStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
         final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceStream)) {

        for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++) {
            PDPage currPage  = document.getPage(pageNumber);
            writeWatermarkOnPage(document, currPage);
        }
        document.save(output);
    }
}

private void writeWatermarkOnPage(PDDocument document, PDPage page) throws IOException {
    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
            document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {

        PDRectangle rect = page.getBBox();
        // Set the opacity
        PDExtendedGraphicsState extendedGraphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        extendedGraphicsState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(0.3f);
        contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(extendedGraphicsState);

        // Add the text
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 75);
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.GRAY);
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(1, 0, 0, 1,
                                                 rect.getUpperRightX() / 4,
                                                 rect.getUpperRightY() / 4);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(at);
        matrix.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        contentStream.setTextMatrix(matrix);
        contentStream.showText("WATERMARK-TEXT");
        contentStream.endText();
    }
}
```

I tried using the Overlay class, but that had the same result. I tried removing the rotation and transform, but that didn't help. Only if I remove the nonStrokingAlphaConstant setting will the opaque white background go away when printed from IE's inline PDF renderer, but then the text isn't transparent anymore.

Is there something else I need to do to tell every PDF reader in every context that the background of the text should be completely transparent?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example [PDF Document that shows this behavior](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0azbjgsc7xe59n/U_007496_01478.PDF?dl=0). On Windows, I just drag & drop this into IE, print it, and the white background of the watermark text covers up the underlying image.

Here is another example [PDF created and watermarked with the same code that actually prints just fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/njdbyj739k9x3o1/U_012345_00001.PDF?dl=0) from IE. The watermark is transparent with no white background.

I believe the difference is that the broken documents are legal sized images, while the working document is letter size. Perhaps something related to scaling is causing the issue?

Comment: 1) is it OK if you print from Adobe Reader? 2) What is the program used in MSIE to display / print PDFs?

Comment: Yes, @Tilman, it's OK if I print from standalone Adobe Reader DC, oddly enough. In MSIE, it is using Adobe Reader to display/print PDFs.

Comment: Please share a sample pdf for which the issue can be observed.

Comment: @mkl, I added example PDF documents and more test results in the post update.

Comment: @Tilman I just discovered a workaround: if I create a PNG with transparent background and overlay it with transparency, it works and prints correctly. I may move forward with this if there isn't a way to use text. I'll post the code once I have it finalized.

Comment: @arogos I could reproduce the issue with your file. I'll look into it to check whether there is something special about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to meet my goal by using a transparent PNG as the watermark instead of adding it as text. The new watermarked files now print correctly from all browsers, including IE. Here is the code I used to add the watermark to every page of the PDF:

```
private static final String WATERMARK_RESOURCE_PATH = "/watermark/hcro_copy.png";

public void watermark(File pdfFile, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try (final InputStream sourceStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
         final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceStream)
    ) {
        for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++) {
            PDPage currPage  = document.getPage(pageNumber);
            writeWatermarkWithTransparentImageOnPage(document, currPage);
        }
        document.save(output);
    }
}

private void writeWatermarkWithTransparentImageOnPage(PDDocument document, PDPage page)
        throws IOException {
    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
            document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
         InputStream watermarkFileStream = getWatermarkFileStream()
    ) {
        // Load watermark image
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(watermarkFileStream);
        PDImageXObject pdxImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, image);

        // Set the opacity
        PDExtendedGraphicsState extendedGraphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
        extendedGraphicsState.setNonStrokingAlphaConstant(0.35f);
        contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(extendedGraphicsState);

        // Center watermark image on page
        PDRectangle rect = page.getBBox();
        int imageX = Math.floorDiv((Math.round(rect.getWidth()) - pdxImage.getWidth()), 2);
        int imageY = Math.floorDiv((Math.round(rect.getHeight()) - pdxImage.getHeight()), 2);

        contentStream.drawImage(pdxImage, imageX, imageY);
    }
}

private InputStream getWatermarkFileStream() {
    try {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(WATERMARK_RESOURCE_PATH);
        return resource.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I'd still be open to a text-only answer, but this works for me now.